# How to rename a variable (Loops to fill multiple matrices)

Tags: vba, loops, variables

Im trying to fill multiple matrices according to inputs from a userform.

Right now i have to create 5 matrices but i want this to be able to change in the future, so i want to create the variables "on the fly" in my loop. I basically want to Create Matrix1, Matrix2, Matrix3 ... Matrixn, but i can't figure how to do it. Any Ideas ?

Following you can see the script --> The two last lines are totally wrong (i know it) but i just added them in hope that you understand what i want to do :)

PS: And most important i should be able to then look to Matrix1(i,j),..., Matrixn(i,j) values easily

Looking Forward your help <3

```
'FicheCalcul ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim Temp4 As String
Dim Temp5 As String
Dim MatrixTemp(3 - 1, 5 - 1) As Double 'm-1,x-1


For i = 1 To 5 'n
    
    
    For j = 0 To 3 - 1 'm-1
    
        For k = 0 To 5 - 1 'X-1
        
            Temp4 = j & "C" & i
            Temp5 = Temp4 & k
            
        
            If UserForm1.Controls(Temp5) = False Then
                MatrixTemp(j, k) = ""
            Else
                If UserForm1.Controls(Temp5) = True Then
                    MatrixTemp(j, k) = k - 2   ' -2 -1 0 1 2
                End If
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
    
    
    Dim ("Matrix"&i)(3-1,5-1) As Double
    ("Matrix"&i) = MatrixTemp
    
Next i
```

Comment: Maybe a 3D Array could work ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have variable variable names. Therefore you need to use arrays.

```
Option Explicit

Sub example()
    
    Dim MatrixTemp(4, 5) As Double
    
    
    'do your matrix stuff here
    MatrixTemp(0, 0) = 1
    MatrixTemp(0, 1) = 2
    MatrixTemp(0, 2) = 3
    
    
    Dim Matrix(4) As Variant 'create an array of 5 matices
    
    Matrix(0) = MatrixTemp 'fill your temp matrix into the first matrix
    
    
    Debug.Print Matrix(0)(0, 2) 'outputs 3
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much i will try it ! What if i create Matrix(4,4,5) would it be equivalent ?

Comment: Depends on what you are exactly trying to do with your matrices. Depends on how you design your project. Actually both is possible but they are slightly different. For example if you need 2D arrays at some point using my approach would be easier (because you have 2D arrays in a 1D array).